# Google Vision OCR - reading morse code from image file

Tags: image-processing, ocr, vision, google-vision, morse-code

I'm trying to read in an image of morse code (dots and dashes) using Google Vision OCR but it's not picking up the symbols very well. Is there a way to make Google Vision pick up the dots and dashes better or is there a different OCR product that can do a better job of recognizing symbols?

Currently I am using the nodejs example as provided by Google Cloud at the moment:

```
const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');

// Creates a client
const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

// Read a remote image as a text document
client
  .documentTextDetection('./resources/morse.png')
  .then(results => {
    const fullTextAnnotation = results[0].fullTextAnnotation;
    console.log(fullTextAnnotation.text);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });
```

Comment: dots/dash recognition are still challenging for OCR, sometimes these symbols are recognized as graphics or noise, so its obvious to get unexpected recognition results. You can try with resizing the image and perform OCR which might improve the result.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! It's a bit frustrating because reading the wiki article on the Timeline of OCR one of the first things they managed to read in the 1930's-50's was supposedly Morse code! I'm going to take a stab at your suggestion and resize the image to see if I can get better results from that. Thanks!